# Can't get done anything with admin.php response

Tags: pages, jquery, ajax

So, i finally got some results with ajax hyperlink -> query to DB.

And now i can see, the console, XHR admin-ajax.php post, with right results in jquery.

Jquery code.Problem is, that anything i do, it does not work.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
 $(".dropdown-item").click( function() {
    var data = { action: 'get_data',
      id: $(this).attr('id')
    };
$.ajax({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: data,
    action: 'get_data',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',    
    function(response) {
        $('.showPerson').html(response);
    }
      });

  });

});
```

get_Data function in function.php

```
function get_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $o=$_POST['id'];
    $result2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `department`, `phone`,`job_title`, `cell_phone`, `image`, `email`, `address`, `room`FROM employee WHERE department_id=" . $o );
//  foreach($result2 as $r){
//  echo  '<div class="info-block bg-grey m-b-2 p-a-2">';
//                  echo '<h4 class="h4 underline-sm">' . $r['firstname'] . " " . $r['lastname'] . " </h4>";
//                  echo '<div class="col-sm-8 text-xs-left">';
//                  echo '  <p class="m-b-1"><b>' .  $r['job_title'] ;
//                  echo        'Tööruum: ' . $r['room']; 
//                  echo    '</b></p>';
//                  echo    '<a href="mailto:' . $r['email'] . '">' .  $r['email'] . '></a>';
//                  echo    '<p class="m-b-0">' . $r['phone'] . " " . $r['cell_phone'] . '</php></p>';
//                  echo '</div>';
//                  echo '<div class=" col-sm-4 text-xs-right m-b-1">';
//                  echo  ' <img src="' .  $r['image'] . '" class="rounded-circle lg" alt="">';
//                  echo '</div>';
//              echo '</div>';
//          echo '</div>';
    //}


    echo json_encode($result2);

    wp_die();

}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data' );

function my_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/getData.js', array('jquery') );
      $data = array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

What i'm doing wrong? I can see the data - but i cant do  anything with it?